# how to write sql subquery with 2 date ranges

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am new to SQL and am having difficulty with the queries needed for the following SSRS report.

We have one table that's lists name, and date. The date corresponds with the date that person has attended an event. We'd like to run a query with a date range, and pull up a list of names that have attended an event in that date range along with ALL of their attendance dates, even if one of the dates is outside the range

so for table

```
NAME, DATE OF ATTENDENCE
ALICE, 1/1/2000
BOB, 1/1/2000
CHARLIE, 1/1.2000
ALICE, 1/1/2001
ALICE, 1/1/2002
BOB, 1/1/2002
```

We would want a to query for a year, say 2002, and then see a list of anyone who had attended an event in 02, and all the other attendance dates for those people, so 2002 would show

```
ALICE, 1/1/2000
ALICE, 1/1/2001
ALICE, 1/1/2002
BOB, 1/1/2000
BOB, 1/1/2002
```

I'm having trouble with how to approach this , I assume I need multiple queries, but cant quite wrap my head around how to do this.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

MC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an `exists` clause:

```
select e.*
from events e
where exists (select 1
              from events e2
              where e2.name = e.name and
                    year(e2.DateOfAttendence) = 2002
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to be using a nested query. Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `when` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Then you could get all the information you requested by using the following query:

```
select * from `events` where name in (
  SELECT distinct name
  FROM `events`
  WHERE `when` >= STR_TO_DATE('24/01/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
  and `when` <= STR_TO_DATE('26/01/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
)
```

..got ninja'd :(..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think subquery is an answer for your problem. subquery returns only a single field.
instead you could use nested queries.

look for something like this

```
Select  *
        From    TimeTable
        Where   Id  In
                    (
                        Select  Id
                                From    TimeTable
                                Where   Date >= TO_DATE('01/01/2002 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') And
                                        Date <   TO_DATE('01/01/2003 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') 
                    )
```